# CircleCI: Best way to verify if docker containers are responding via HTTP

Tags: shell, http, curl, docker, circleci

here is an example of part of my circle.yml how I am currently verifying if my mongodb docker container is responding to an http request, so that I can verify if the response is ok and that the server is up.

```
test:
  override:
    # RUN DOCKER CONTAINERS
    # MongoDB -------------
    - docker run --name MongoDB -p 27018:27018 -d mongo:3.0 mongod --port 27018 --replSet "rs"; sleep 10
    - curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -v http://localhost:27018
```

with this `curl` it's working fine, **sometimes**.
**And sometimes it gives me this error**:

`curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -v http://localhost:27018
* About to connect() to localhost port 27018 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0`

How can I improve this, to make it more reliable so my tests won't sometimes pass and sometimes fail, if I rebuild the same build?

*note: this question was also asked on [discuss.circleci.com](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/best-way-to-verify-if-docker-containers-are-responding-via-http/1283)*

Comment: I noticed you got your answer on discuss.circleci.com .  While it seems to be "we were having networking problems ourselves at that time" it might still be nice to have such an update to this question or even a self-answer to this for future reader, should they have an similar outage again.